# Error When clicking on white space on a page in XPages

Tags: xpages

One of my clients has a replica copy of a database on two different Domino Servers. On one of the servers if the user clicks on any white space on a view or form they get the following error:
[image]

While the database on the test server does not throw this error. My server likewise does not throw this error either. as far as I can determine they are both running the same release of Domino.

I have search my code but can't find any reason for this error.

Any pointers where to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for eventHandlers on your page, looking for one associated to a component that does not have an ID. I think what happens is that if you have an eventHandler on a button, comboBox etc that does not have an ID, it gets associated to whatever contains the button, comboBox etc. So it triggers when you click in that area.

If you find one, add an ID and it will resolve the click problem.

I'm not 100% sure what the refreshId issue is, maybe the eventHandler in question is set `refreshMode="partial"` but not refreshId set, so it's trying to refresh the component containing the eventHandler, which is the one that doesn't have an ID. I could understand how that would cause a problem.

Comment: Paul, I will check this but any idea why it would happen on one server but not on another? Identical Code!

Comment: Found a Button with no id= and a partial refresh that was pointing to the wrong thing. Think That fixed it.